# Bind an objects union to ng-template

Tags: angular

I have response from server with array different objects. Example:

```
[
 {
   type: 'car',
   title: 'Benz',
   vehicle: {
     type: 'E Class',
     gearbox: 'A',
     ac: true,
   },
 },

 {
   type: 'hotel',
   title: 'Remparts',
   hotel: {
     rating: '8.5',
   },
 },

 {
   type: 'place',
   title: 'Hyde',
   place: {
     category: 'Park',
   },
 },
]
```

My task is to associate an object with its template.

```
<app-card *ngFor="let item of cards" [viewRef]="currentView">

  <!-- logic of the template selection  -->
  <ng-template>
  
  </ng-template>
</app-card>
```

and card component

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="viewRef">
</ng-container>
```

How to bind a specific object to a template?

[image]

I had a solution create interface and with ngSwitch choose templatRef, but it's very ugly, is there a better solution?

```
export interface CardDataModel {
  type: string;
  title: string;
  st: string;
  vehicle?: any;
  hotel?: any;
  place?: any;
}
```

Comment: You could use context property to set value of ng-template, https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet#description

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solve my problem. Maybe I did not explain correctly. I have attached image. Each object has its own template. The templates are similar but the content is different. I am looking for the best way to find out which object is in the array to apply template.

Comment: So you mean each object has different ng-template to bind?

Comment: @Chellappanவ That's what I mean.